# Are Plenty Of Ammo cards discarded after using them?

Tags: zombicide, zombicide-black-plague

A friend who recently bought Zombicide: Invader was pretty sure that you have to discard "Plenty of Ammo" cards after using their ability. He said he also checked online and found rules stating this (no idea where he found those). He stated that the word "once" in the card text was supposed to mean just that.

Is he right, though?
**Do you have to discard a "Plenty of Ammo" card after using its ability?**

Here is an example from Zombicide: Black Plague (but the wording is the same for all Zombicide editions, afaik)

[image: You may re-roll all Ranged Attacks once with weapons with the Arrows keyword. The new result takes the place of the previous one.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plenty of Ammo cards can be used once per action and are not discarded when used.

Some card types, including “Plenty Of Ammo” cards, are always in effect.

> **INVENTORY**
>
> Each Survivor can carry up to five pieces of Equipment but
>   can only have two equipped and ready to use (one in each hand) at any
>   given time. While all weapons must be in a hand slot in order to use
>   them (whether to attack or to open a door), other items, such as the
>   Goalie Mask, Flashlight and **Plenty of Ammo** cards, ***are always in
>   effect, even while in the reserve slots.***

https://www.zombicide.com/dl/rulebook-zombicide-season-1.pdf - page 9

e.g.:

> **Plenty of Arrows**
>
> You may re-roll ***all*** Ranged Attacks ***once*** with weapons with the Arrows
>   keyword. The new result takes the place of the previous one.

This means that as long as this card is in your inventory, ***each*** Ranged Attack action using a weapon with the Arrow keyword can be re-rolled ***once***.